# Delphi Check for Default Printer Failing

Tags: delphi, printing

I use the code below to prevent an exception when someone tries to print but doesn't have a default printer set. I've gotten a report from a user using the software remotely with citrix who has a network printer as the default printer. It raises an exception at the call to GetPrinter with the message "There is no default printer currently selected". They have no problems printing from other applications. What would be going wrong here?

```
function CheckForDefaultPrinter: boolean;
var
  FDevice:     PChar;
  FDriver:     PChar;
  FPort:       PChar;
  FHandle:     THandle;
  CurrentPrinterName: string;
begin
  //ensure default printer selected - bypass printer.pas bug
  Printer.PrinterIndex := Printer.PrinterIndex;
  GetMem (FDevice, 255);
  GetMem (FDriver, 255);
  GetMem (FPort, 255);
  try
    try
      Printers.Printer.GetPrinter(FDevice, FDriver, FPort, FHandle);
    except
      on E:Exception do
        ShowMessage(E.Message);
    end;
    CurrentPrinterName := FDevice;
  finally
    if FDevice <> nil then FreeMem (FDevice, 255);
    if FDriver <> nil then FreeMem (FDriver, 255);
    if FPort <> nil then FreeMem (FPort, 255);
  end;

  if CurrentPrinterName = '' then
  begin
    MessageDlg('You do not have a default printer defined.' +
               #13#13 + 'Please select a printer before running a report.'+
               #13#13 + 'Or the default printer name is blank. Please assign the printer a name.',
               mtError,[mbOK],0);
    Result:= False;
  end
  else
    Result:= True;
end;
```

Comment: what Is the value of  `Printer.PrinterIndex` ? and yes, it is pretty possible when there is NO default printer in system, that is absolutely valid case and you have to check for it too. Where do you check above that the user does not have any default printers? Id there are none you should show user the list of printers and ask to select one, a simple form with TRadioGroup would do at least, or better a standard windows PrinterSelect dialog

Comment: Your heap allocation is odd. Why test for assigned in the finally? You know it will be. And why heap allocate? What's wrong with the stack? This is also that RTL function for which it is impossible to know how much space to allocate.

Comment: @Arioch 'The Printer.PrinterIndex should actually be set to -1 to check the Default Printer, right? Setting it to itself seems useless. That's probably part of the problem. I don't recall what the printer.pas bug was or how this would bypass it.

Comment: By the time you can call `Printer.GetPrinter`, the problem has already occurs (it happens the first time you access `Printer`, even if that's the call to `GetPrinter` in your code above). Call the WinAPI function [GetDefaultPrinter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) directly instead.

Comment: @fullerm and I ask you again - what is your code supposed to do when there is NO DEFAULT printer in system at all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs before the code you posted can check it, because it fails during the first access to `Printer`.

You should use the WinAPI [GetDefaultPrinter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function directly instead to see if a default printer exists, before attempting to use the global `Printer`. Here's a sample console application (which utilizes an easier declaration of the function than the one contained in recent versions of Delphi) to demonstrate how to do so. The sample was compiled in XE 10 Seattle and tested on Windows 7 64-bit.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils, WinAPI.Windows;

function GetDefaultPrinter(Buffer: PChar; var BufferSize: DWord): BOOL; stdcall;
  external 'winspool.drv' name 'GetDefaultPrinterW'; // GetDefaultPrinterA on pre-Unicode Delphi versions

var
  Buff: string;
  BuffSize, Err: DWord;
begin
  // Get size of buffer needed. 
  GetDefaultPrinter(nil, BuffSize);
  SetLength(Buff, BuffSize);
  // If this call fails, and GetLastError returns
  // ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, there is no default printer assigned.
  if GetDefaultPrinter(PChar(Buff), BuffSize) then
    WriteLn('Default printer: ', Buff)
  else
  begin
    Err := GetLastError();
    if Err = ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND then
      WriteLn('No default printer assigned')
    else
      WriteLn('Failed. Error: ', Err);
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Note that the return value includes the terminating NULL (`#0`) according to the documentation. To remove it, simply `SetLength(Buff, Length(Buff) - 1)` after the call to `GetDefaultPrinter` returns.

Comment: According to the Win API docs, GetDefaultPrinter always fails when called with a nil buffer. So that first if statement should be changed. Other than that a great answer.

Comment: @fullerm: Funny thing - I was driving home from work a few minutes ago, and thought about that exact issue. I was going to check my answer again when I got home, and found your comment mentioning that same thing. :-) Corrected the comment. Thanks.

Comment: @Trenton_M: You can't plagiarize someone else's answer and add it to mine. That's an inappropriate edit. I've rolled it back. I've edited in a more appropriate note to include the information provided by RodD in the other answer.

Comment: @RodD posted it as a comment to an answer, "so to be clear this is NOT a separate ANSWER but a comment/correction on Answer #2", which will probably be deleted in review as, not an answer. What they wrote, is right below your post. 
 Additionally, plagiarizing is taking credit for someone else's work, without attribution, which I did not do.   Additionally, there are many examples of community maintained answers, that grow as new versions or methods are released.  There is strong precedent for community maintained answer.

Comment: @Trenton_M: Community-maintained is one thing. Copy/pasting an answer verbatim is not the same thing. Attribution doesn't mean *based upon an answer/comment*, which is what you wrote in your comment above as the only *attribution*. Plagiarism is using content belonging to someone else without their permission and using it as yours, which is what you did when you added it to *my answer*.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can assume that if there is more than 0 (zero) printers then there is a default printer.
This assmption is safe except if your application is running as a service.

So all you need is this:

`if (Printer.Printers.Count=0) then
  ShowMessage('Please install a printer before attempting to print.');`

You need to make this check before you access most other properties/methods on the Printer object.

If your application is running as a service there will be no default printer. Here PrinterIndex will be -1 until you assign a value in code.

Comment: `On Windows you can assume that if there is more than 0 (zero) printers then there is a default printer` no you can not

Comment: This does not always work, as accessing `Printer` causes the exception before you can get to `Printers.Count`. See http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=100256. You cannot assume that if there is at least one printer installed that there is a default, either.

Answer (score -3):

I tested your code with Delphi XE6, Win7Pro. Just changed a line

```
GetMem (FPort, 255);
 try
  try
    Printer.GetPrinter(FDevice, FDriver, FPort, FHandle); // HERE

except
  on E:Exception do
    ShowMessage(E.Message);
end;
```

It works with a networked printer as default, even with cable unplugged.

Comment: You've just removed the reference to the Printers Unit. Maybe in XE6 GetPrinter is in a different unit but in older versions of Delphi, removing the unit reference will have no effect.

Comment: Removing the `Printers.` does nothing meaningful if Printers is in the uses clause. Also, unplugging a network printer does not make it no longer the default printer; it just means that the default printer is off-line. Your answer makes zero difference to the problem.