# Floating point error in QuickReport Delphi10.3 through Citrix launcher and print blank pages

Tags: delphi, quickreports

We have an application launched in one of our servers and clients accessing it via Citrix. We have now migrated Delphi7 to Delphi10.3. Now we are experiencing a floating point error while printing our reports developed in QuickReport 6. Unfortunately we are not getting this error in our local environment(No RDB and Citrix) and the reports are printing quiet nicely. But when we deploy the same application in our server and accessing it via Citrix gives the error and prints blank pages. We could not suspect it as a Citirx issue since other applications deployed in the Citrix prints well.

One more interesting thing is that, when the user clicks on the print setup in the Quick report and click Ok and then print the report prints it nicely in the Citrix as well. As the report settings are not saved permanently we could not recommend the same to the users.

Comment: You might have a look at this Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/q/19187479/2663863.

Comment: What is the exact floating point error that is being raised? Does your local environment use same floating point delimiter as the server does? If you hard-coded your application to use certain delimiter and then run it on computer hat is using different delimiter it could lead to many problems.

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34339592/delphi-check-for-default-printer-failing)

Comment: you can share some code snippets, error logs, and any useful data to help others answer your question.

Comment: @SilverWarior Just the "Floating point Division By Zero" error and getting a blank page as output. No delimiters hard-coded, its pure and simple

Comment: @novonimo Its just a "QuickRep.Print" . I have my CutePdfWriter installed as default printer and  expecting the pdf to be saved. Its works in local and earlier version also in the network. Now the upgrade throws me this error and a blank page with no data

Comment: @MartynA It only hides the error. But the report has no data, only blank pages

Comment: @Olivier I have my CutePdfWriter as my default printer. So it is not like not getting the printer